# How to read Power Bi Dataset in Power Automate?

Tags: azure, powerbi, power-automate

How to read Power Bi Dataset in Power Automate ? We are trying to achieve that visually and programmatically.

We need to create a flow in Power Automate based on the values we get from Power Bi Dataset.

OR

We would like to achieve the same from Power BI with Power Automate integration, here we are able to read the power bi dataset and create a power automate flow, the challenge we are facing is the flow is triggered  onclick of a button, can this be triggered on schedule instead?[image]

Answer (score -1):

there is a power automate integrated into Power Bi, you can make it trigger itself thanks to a recurrence and then use your actual power automate as a child in that recurrence automation. Let me know if that led to something better.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the "Run a query against a dataset" action under the Power BI connector. You can have a normal scheduled flow, and with the said the action, run a DAX query on your dataset.